# ASP.NET Forms - DataBindingComplete not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone explain to me why my `EmployeeSearchResultsList_DataBindingComplete` is not firing? It was my understanding that after the `RowDataBound` is done binding data, then it would automatically fire `DataBindingComplete`.

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="employeeSearchResultsList" runat="server" CssClass="GridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EmployeeSearchResultsList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="EmployeeSearchResultsList_RowDataBound" OnDataBindingComplete="EmployeeSearchResultsList_DataBindingComplete">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Select" CommandName="select" Text="Select" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="lastName" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="firstName" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Middle Name" DataField="middleName" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="status" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

RowDataBound:

```
protected void EmployeeSearchResultsList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Magic
}
```

DataBindingComplete:

```
protected void EmployeeSearchResultsList_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
   // It does not hit here
}
```

Comment: Are you actually calling `bind()` on the DGV?

Comment: I am. Neglected to post it. It occurs before this. Essentially getting a list of employees, and binding to the gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GridView does not have a `DataBindingComplete` event. Only the `DataGridView` Control for Webforms has that.

From your question it is not clear what you want to do with that event. Maybe we can provide an alternative.

Comment: So there's no way in ASP.NET Forms to detect when DataBind() has completed?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. See all events [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Essentially, I need to set a tabIndex for the items defined within the Gridview. My thought was to catch when the databind was complete to accomplish this.

Comment: Doing stuff with the items in a GridView are usually done in the`OnRowDataBound` event. Or loop all rows after you have called `DataBind()`.